# Every URL is Redirecting (301) to Non trailing link URL

Tags: magento2, magento-2.3

I am running into a problem in Magento 2.3.

Every url is redirecting (301) to non trailing url

For example

shop.com/test/ is always going to shop.com/test

Is this bad for SEO?

In case yes how can i manage it within magento admin?

Thank you.

Comment: It's not bad for SEO, as long as it's consistent with the canonical URL

Comment: @Simone thank you. the canonical is shop.com/test however i am using ahrefs and also google is complaining about it. 

on a general approach if i change now the urls to the trailing slashes will be affect anything?

Comment: As far as I know it doesn't really matter. You can have it the other way around if you prefer (i.e. shop.com/test redirecting 301 to trailing slash), but why do you want to change it? Did Google recommend doing so? I'm not an SEO expert by the way (nor Magento, for that matter), so you might want to double check this, but the one thing I know is that the canonical URL is the authoritative one, and that should always be the same you see in the address bar.

Answer (score 0):

> Is this bad for SEO?

The answer is simply 'no':

> If you have a website that is already established, then you should
> probably use whatever your site is using today.
>
> In other words, if your site’s URLs do or don’t use a trailing slash,
> then stick to that approach. There is certainly no SEO benefit to
> switching.

Source: https://searchfacts.com/url-trailing-slash/